# Как получить effective permissions?

Tags: python, c, windows, powershell, permissions

Мне нужно получить **effective permissions**. Как лучше всего это сделать?

Я пытаюсь использовать **win32security**, но функции **GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(trustee)** необходим параметр **PyTRUSTEE**. И я не знаю, как установить его правильно.

Результат должен быть таким же, как при использовании  **Get-EffectiveAccess** в **PowerShell**.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мы пробовали использовать **Authz.h**, но тогда в **Windows Event Viewer** появлялись **Audit failure**.

Также мы пробовали использовать **GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl** из **Aclapi.h**, но она могла стать причиной зависания, если у нас было много файлов.

Comment: Пожалуйста исправьте вопрос переведя на русский язык. На русском SO принято задавать вопросы только на русском языке.